# I can't create MFMailComposeViewController's object

Tags: objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I can't create MFMailComposeViewController's object. Can you help me?

I've tried 2 methods and it doesn't work:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mf = [MFMailComposeViewController new];
```

or

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mf = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

Anybody knows what's happen?
Thanks.

P.S. It doesn't work on iPad 2 with ios 4.3.3, but it work on iPad 1 with ios 4.3.2

Comment: And what you are doing after this line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if [`[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/MFMailComposeViewController/canSendMail) (documentation linked) returns YES.

I suspect it's not, in your case.

If it does return yes, is "mf" set to null after you do alloc/init ?

Also make sure the MessageUI.framework is added to your project.  [In case you need it, here's a tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-2-in-app-email-messageui/).

Answer (score 2):

I use the second format:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mf = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

Make sure:

- You have added the `MessageUI.framework` to your project
- You have added `#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>` to your class header file
- You declare `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` and any relevant methods you require

If the device does not have any mail accounts setup when you create and later call `[self presentModalViewController:mf animated:YES];` then you'll get an Apple alert view informing you of the situation.

Comment: Seems to crash if you don't have that on iOS 6.1

Answer (score 1):

1)Add MessageUI.framework to your project

2)import #import  to ur view controller

3)declare MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate methods

```
        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mail setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"mail id", nil]];
        [mail setSubject:@"Contact Us"];
        [mail setMessageBody:@"If U want any information u can send the mail <div> " isHTML:YES];
        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:nil];
        [mail release];
```